# Identify Object Cache User in Web Application

Tags: object-cache

Would anyone know how i could find out what user is assigned to the portal super user and portal super reader accounts for object cache?

Is there a listing in CA or something i could source up for each web application with powershell?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Get current superuser/superreader accounts PowerShell One-liner](http://sharepointrelated.com/2012/05/09/get-current-superusersuperreader-accounts-powershell-one-liner/)

```
Get-SPWebApplication | 
%{Write-Host “Web Application: ” $_.url “`nSuper user: ” $_.properties ["portalsuperuseraccount"] “`nSuper reader: ” $_.properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] “`n”}
```